# Angularjs Add Data to templateCache

Tags: angularjs, dialog

I am having some problems with showing data in templateCache...

If the "edit" button is clicked, a custom dialog is showing up and the UserData is supposed to show up in input fields to be edited.

I used to get the Data from a Sql Select and everything worked fine , but now i have saved all the data in $cookieStorage and then i wanted to take the Information from the $cookieStorage and then add it to the Dialoge.

The Function do everything it supposed to be, but the Dialog is showing up when the Function is completly done! But I need it To be loaded and then to put the data into the fields.

Thats my Code:

```
var listApp = angular.module('listpp', ['ui.bootstrap','dialogs','ngCookies']);

listApp.controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope, $dialogs,$cookieStore) {
....
$scope.u_edit = function (index) 
{   
    dlg = $dialogs.create('/dialogs/editUser.html','editUserCtrl',{},{key:false ,back:'static'});
    $cookieStore.aktuser =  $cookieStore.user[index-1];
    -stuff to get user infos and react to button clicks in dialog- 
})
.run(['$templateCache',function($templateCache,$scope,$cookieStore){
    $templateCache.put('/dialogs/editUser.html', 
    ....
    +'<input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" ng-model="user.id">'
    +'<input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="user.name">'
     ....
   }]);
```

The Problem is, that i can't fill the Fields when the dialog isn't loaded, but i dont know how to to catch the info, that the dialog is loaded to fill the fileds with the data.

There is a method for the angular-dialog-service that is called opened, but that is still happening before the dialoge is loaded....

...so how do i get the data in that dialog??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody cares:

I saved all the needed data in a cookieStore, in the CustomDialog Controller for the templateCache I saved that data in $scope and used it in the template and when i click the save button i save the new data in a $cookieStore again!!